# How to bind one application with another

Tags: java, python, windows

Is there any way i can bind my custom application with some other desktop application i.e. can i force start an application when i launch some other application.

Example - can i launch google chrome whenever i open adobe reader i.e bind them together

Like whenever i open my adobe reader, along with adobe reader google chrome should also launch

is this possible?

I have made an application which should launch as soon as i launch my adobe reader

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can create a new desktop shortcut or edit a desktop shortcut to set run two application at once.

Comment: Can you just make a script that opens both?

Comment: So you are trying to make some sort of malware application.??

Comment: its not a malware...it is kind of utility for reader

Comment: @KevinGuan how to do that

Comment: @MalikBrahimi how will a script solve the problem

Comment: If you make a script, it can open both at once.

Answer (score 0):

Like @MalikBrahimi said, use a script is more easy. This is an example

```
@echo off
start "" "C:\Program Files\test\test.exe"
start "" "C:\Program Files\test\test.exe"
```

this script will run these two application at once(and you can add more). Just copy these code into a .bat file and change the path, then create a desktop shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

With the `os` module of the Python standard library, opening both programs with a script is but a trifle:

```
os.startfile('path/to/reader/shortcut') # start the reader program
os.startfile('path/to/chrome/shortcut') # start the chrome program
```